How to access Microsoft Graph API in Jenkins for Robot Framework Tests
I am facing an issue where a Microsoft Graph API call is failing when executed through a Jenkins pipeline, where it was supposed to show the contents of a specific mail being configured.
The entire framework is build on Robot Framework with custom library written to handle the Microsoft Graph API calls. The code for custom library is written below:
import os
import msal
import requests
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request, session, render_template_string
import logging

load_dotenv(override=True)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'replace-with-a-random-secret-key'

log_file_path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "flask_app.log")

logging.basicConfig(filename=log_file_path, level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')

client_id = os.getenv('AZURE_CLIENT_ID')
print(client_id)
client_secret = os.getenv('AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET')
print(client_secret)
authority = os.getenv('AZURE_AUTHORITY', f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{os.getenv('TENANT_ID')}")
print(authority)
redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:5000/getAToken'  # Change this to match your app's redirect URI
scope = ['User.Read']  # Delegated permission to read the user's profile

client = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id,
    authority=authority,
    client_credential=client_secret
)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    logging.info("Index route accessed")
    if 'access_token' in session:
        return render_template_string('''
            <title>Flask App - Home</title>
            <h1>Welcome</h1>
            <p>Access token found in session.</p>
            <a href="/graphCall">Call Graph API</a>
        ''')
    else:
        return render_template_string('''
            <title>Flask App - Login</title>
            <p>Please <a href="/login">log in</a> to continue.</p>
        ''')

@app.route('/login')
def login():
    logging.info("Login route accessed")
    # Redirect the user to Azure AD to log in and get an authorization code
    auth_url = client.get_authorization_request_url(scopes=scope, redirect_uri=redirect_uri)
    return redirect(auth_url)

@app.route('/getAToken')
def authorized():
    logging.info("getAtoken route accessed")
    # Exchange the authorization code for an access token
    code = request.args.get('code')
    if code:
        token_result = client.acquire_token_by_authorization_code(code, scopes=scope, redirect_uri=redirect_uri)
        if 'access_token' in token_result:
            session['access_token'] = token_result['access_token']
            return redirect(url_for('graph_call'))
        else:
            return f"Error acquiring token: {token_result.get('error_description')}"
    else:
        return "No authorization code found in the request."

@app.route('/graphCall')
def graph_call():
    logging.info("graphCall route accessed")
    access_token = session.get('access_token')
    
    if not access_token:
        logging.error("Access token is missing, redirecting to login.")
        return redirect(url_for('login'))

    api_url = ('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$search="USPTO: Your authentication code"' "&$top=3")
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'
    }

    try:
        response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers)
        response.raise_for_status()  # Raise an HTTPError for bad responses (4xx and 5xx)
        
        emails = response.json().get('value', [])
        email_details = []
        
        for email in emails:
            subject = email.get('subject', 'No Subject')
            sender = email.get('from', {}).get('emailAddress', {}).get('name', 'Unknown Sender')
            body_content = email.get('body', {}).get('content', 'No Content')
            email_details.append({
                'subject': subject,
                'sender': sender,
                'body_content': body_content
            })

        return render_template_string('''
            <title>Flask App - Graph API</title>
            <h1>Email Details</h1>
            {% for email in email_details %}
                <p><b>Subject:</b> {{ email.subject }}</p>
                <p><b>Sender:</b> {{ email.sender }}</p>
                <h3>Email Body</h3>
                <div>{{ email.body_content|safe }}</div>
                <hr>
            {% endfor %}
        ''', email_details=email_details)

    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        logging.error(f"Request to Graph API failed: {str(e)}")
        return f"Error: Unable to fetch emails. Details: {str(e)}"

    except KeyError as e:
        logging.error(f"Unexpected response format: Missing key {str(e)}")
        return f"Error: Unexpected response format. Missing key: {str(e)}"

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"An unexpected error occurred: {str(e)}")
        return f"Error: An unexpected error occurred. Details: {str(e)}"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=5000)

The Robot Framework test script code is written below:
Login To Mail Box & Get Pair Code
    Execute Javascript    window.open('${FLASK_APP_URL}', '_blank');
    Switch Window   Flask App - Login
    Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    60s    2s    Click Element    ${FLASK_APP_LOGIN_BTN}
    Wait Until Page Contains Element    ${OUTLOOK_NEXT_BTN_&_SIGNIN_BTN}
    Input Text    ${OUTLOOK_USERNAME}    ${outlook_uname}
    Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    60s    2s    Click Element    ${OUTLOOK_NEXT_BTN_&_SIGNIN_BTN}
    Wait Until Page Contains Element    ${OUTLOOK_NEXT_BTN_&_SIGNIN_BTN}
    Input Text    ${OUTLOOK_PASSWORD}    ${outlook_pass}
    Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    60s    2s    Click Element    ${OUTLOOK_NEXT_BTN_&_SIGNIN_BTN}
    Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    60s    2s    Click Element 
   xpath=//input[@id="idSIButton9"]

    Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    60s    2s    Page Should Contain Element    ${PAIR_CODE_TEXT_VAL}
    ${rows}    Get WebElements    ${PAIR_CODE_TEXT_VAL}
    ${row_count}    Get Length    ${rows}
    Log    Number of rows: ${row_count}
    ${pair_codes}    Create List
    FOR    ${row}    IN RANGE    1    ${row_count + 1}
        ${text}    Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    60s    2s    Get Text    xpath=(//table[@bgcolor="#ffffff"]/tbody/tr[3]/td/b)[${row}]
        Append To List    ${pair_codes}    ${text}
    END
    Log    ${pair_codes}
    Set Global Variable    ${pair_codes}
    [Return]    ${pair_codes}

The execution takes place without any failure till a point where ${OUTLOOK_NO_BTN} and is fails in the next step where it has to check the availability of an element i.e., ${PAIR_CODE_TEXT_VAL} (below is  the screenshot attached for reference)

I don't find any issue when I execute the same test case on my local machine in headless mode.

Any idea what the reason could be and how to solve it?
Thanks in advance for your help

Error is pretty clear; your browser cannot access the given url and error is "connection refused". This is because A) there's nothing running on localhost with given port or B) theres a firewall blocking the access.  Issue is most likely that you are trying to do OAUTH authentication and you have "localhost:5000" as redirect url and you do not have a local response server up and running to receive the token. Are you sure your flask is running and listening on localhost port 5000 ?

also, this feels like pure python question, nothing to do with jenkins or robot framework..

@rasjani, Yes, the flask app is running on localhost with port 5000
link

but the error in the page says "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED". Either you have firewall blocking it  or flask has crashed/stopped.
